# SQL Alchemy order_by not ordering on a join?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

This has to be super simple but I'm stuck.  I used order_by a lot for simple queries but for some reason it won't work on a join as seen below.

Here is my query:

```
g.items = db.session.query(Executor).join("listed").\
                     order_by(Executor.executor_order.desc()).\
                     filter_by(Executor.will_id == g.profile.id).all()
```

Here is the sql result from the above query - totally ignores the order_by part for some reason:

```
SELECT executor.id AS executor_id, executor.will_id AS   
       executor_will_id, executor.listed_people_id AS 
       executor_listed_people_id, executor.executor_order AS
       executor_executor_order FROM executor WHERE executor.will_id = :will_id_1
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Why is it completely ignoring the .order_by, even if I put it before the filter_by?

Here is the executor Model - the join appears to work (I need to bang around it some more to make sure):

```
class Executor(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    will_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('will.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))

    listed_people_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('listed_people.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    executor_order = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=True)

    #relationship - so I can call Executor.listed_people for a list.
    listed_people = db.relationship('ListedPeople', backref='executor')
```

Comment: Your join doesn't appear to work either? Are you sure that's the correct query? What does your `Executor` model look like?